# binary operator |= cannot be applied to two AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions operands

Tags: quickblox, avaudiosession, swift3

Error on binary operator |= cannot be applied to two AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions operands in swift 3.1. Need help

here is my code

```
QBRTCAudioSession.instance().initialize { (configuration: QBRTCAudioSessionConfiguration) in

        configuration.categoryOptions != AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution i found

```
QBRTCAudioSession.instance().initialize { (configuration: QBRTCAudioSessionConfiguration) in

        configuration.categoryOptions = [configuration.categoryOptions, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth]
}
```

Comment: `configuration.categoryOptions.union(.allowBluetooth)`